# ConstructorNotFoundException when mocking java.sql.Timestemp object

Tags: java, powermock

With this code:

```
Timestamp timestamp = PowerMock.createMock(Timestamp.class);
PowerMock.expectNew(Timestamp.class, new Class[] {Long.class}, System.currentTimeMillis()).andReturn(timestamp);
```

I am getting this error:

> org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.ConstructorNotFoundException: Failed
>   to lookup constructor with parameter types [ java.lang.Long ] in class
>   java.sql.Timestamp.   at
>   org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.getConstructor(WhiteboxImpl.java:250)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.doExpectNew(PowerMock.java:1825)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock.expectNew(PowerMock.java:1806)

Answer (score 1):

`Timestamp` takes `long`, not `Long` as constructor parameter. Try `long.class` instead.

Comment: thanks Kaya for your help  but when I call PowerMock.replay(timestamp, Timestamp.class);
PowerMock.verify(timestamp, Timestamp.class); then i am getting below error  java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expectation failure on verify:
    java.sql.Timestamp(1431344562673): expected: 1, actual: 0